# reCAPTCHA - Enable Submit button if passed

Tags: php, forms, required, recaptcha

I have a `form` which a user will complete with `required` `fields`. When all the `required` `fields` are completed, the `submit` `button` can be clicked to send the data.

I have been looking into googles reCAPTCHA, which seems to be working. However, is there a way I can put this as a `required` `field`? Currently, when the `form` is completed, the user can `submit` the `form` without verifying them self with the reCAPTCHA. Where as I would like the `button` to only become available once the `required` `fields` are completed.

---

Code Added as requested. Don't think it will be useful but this is all I have so far (as I have been trying figure out a way how to do this)

```
<form role="form" method="post" id="get_started_form" action="<?php echo base_url('auth/get_started')?>" data-toggle="validator" enctype="multipart/form-data">    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label>First Name</label>
                <input name="first_name" type="text" class="form-control" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z\-.,\s]+$" data-error="Please use text or symbols (- . ,) only." placeholder="First Name" id="first_name" maxlength="50" tabindex="1">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label>Last Name</label>
                <input name="last_name" type="text" class="form-control" required pattern="^[a-zA-Z\-.,\s]+$" data-error="Please use text or symbols (- . ,) only." placeholder="Last Name" id="last_name" maxlength="50" tabindex="2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group has-feedback">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" required placeholder="Text@Text.Domain" id="email" maxlength="100" tabindex="3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="KEY_HERE"></div>
            <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="get_staretd_form_button" class="btn btn-primary">Get Started</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: post some code here

Comment: You'll probably want to use JS for this instead

Comment: Code speaks louder than words.

Comment: @Blueblazer172 Code added. Its just a standard form with the link as I have been trying to get it set as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [ReCAPTCHA](http://formvalidation.io/examples/validating-google-recaptcha/#final-code)

.....................